# Assembling JST PH connectors

Tags: pcb, connector, wire, header

I assembled a few JST PHR-4 connectors with wires (manually crimped [SPH-002T-P0.5S](http://media.digikey.com/photos/JST%20Photos/SPH-002T-P0.5S_sml.jpg) crimp terminals with AWG24 wires and inserted it into the [PHR-4](http://media.digikey.com/photos/JST%20Photos/PHR-4.jpg) connector housing). When I tried to join connector header with the mating [PH male pin header](http://media.digikey.com/photos/JST%20Photos/B4B-PH-K-S_sml.jpg) on PCB, I find I canno to insert it there. I don't want to apply too much force to connector, to avoid PCB damage. What can be the problem there?
I suspect this may be due to I created connector using manual crimp tools, and this can no provide the required accuracy.
Here is [datasheet](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/ePH.pdf).

Comment: You probably crushed the pin openings while you were crimping. Just a guess.

Comment: You may have also distorted the contact so that when it entered the contact housing the pin entry slot in the housing is not lining up with the pin entry slot in the contact.

Comment: I am not immediately familiar with your contacts but many times when you try to hand crimp with a general purpose low cost crimper you destroy the contact alignment features designed to guide and hold the contact in the housing. As such the pins may have even been inserted rotated 180 degrees from the proper position. This can almost certainly cause failure of contacts to mate properly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the correct pin crimp tool, either YRS-240 or YRM-240?

http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/JST%20PDFs/Hand%20and%20Crimping%20Tools.pdf

These tools run around $1000 each, and are kinda tricky to use. If used correctly though, these make perfect crimps.

Comment: I used PA-09 crimper http://engineer.jp/_products/pa09/p/pa09_new.jpg I hadn't noticed visually that pin opening were damaged. However, 2.0mm pitch terminals are so small in size.
Which area of terminal holds the pin, 1 or 2? http://s1.postimg.org/8h6nbmhbz/SPH_002_T_P0_5_S.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure. If you take a closeup picture of your crimps that might be more helpful though.

Comment: Is it possible to use other 2.0mm pitch generic OEM connectors with JST PH male header in place of PHR-4?